# RAID 5\6 пенальти

Tags: администрирование, raid

Наткнулся на таблицу с пенальти на запись для RAID 5 и 6 и не могу до конца понять по какой причине при записи данных на RAID массив необходимо предварительно считать данные... Таблица доступна [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/164325/):

> В RAID 5 чтобы записать данные происходит 4 операции (Чтение существующих данных, четность RAID, Запись новых данных, Запись новой четности) тем самым пенальти в RAID 5 составляет 4.

Так же не нашел нигде объяснения, почему пенальти не кратно количеству дисков. Например, если нам необходимо выполнить запись 128Кб с чанком в 64Кб на RAID5 из трех дисков, то мы, по идее, должны получить пенальти равное трем: две операции записи данных (по одной на каждый диск) + одна операция записи четности.

Comment: Чтобы посчитать новую чётность, наверное?

Comment: Четность в данном случае - операция xor на чатками входного набор данных. Возможно это и так, но все равно не вижу связи с уже записанными данными...

Comment: Не просто входных данных, а входных данных со всех дисков (если статьи в интернете меня не обманывают). И с очень высокой вероятностью записываемые данные охватывают только какой-то один диск, а не все сразу, поэтому придётся прочитать недостающие данные с остальных дисков

Comment: (Хотя нет, со всеми дисками я наверное перегнул. Чтобы посчитать, изменится ли чётность после записи нового куска данных, достаточно прочитать старый кусок данных с затронутого записью диска и, сравнив с новым куском данных, вычислить изменившиеся биты, и на основе этой информации прочитать и соответствующим образом обновить чётность)

Comment: Вот тут описано: https://support.huawei.com/enterprise/en/knowledge/EKB1100050033. У RAID5 penalty действительно 4. Чтение и запись происходит не на всех дисках, а только на одном (и диске чётности).